# Swift Navigation Bar is changing the Status Bar text color

Tags: ios, swift

The navigation bar is setting the color of the status bar to black, unless I change its `barStyle` to `.blackTranslucent`. When that's set, the status bar text is white, which is what I want, but the border on the bottom of the navigation bar becomes translucent as well, and I would like for that to be visible. Here's what I mean:

when `nav_bar.barStyle = .default`:

[image]

when `nav_bar.barStyle = .blackTranslucent`:

[image]

Is there any way to  get the best of both worlds, where I could have white status bar text as well as a visible navigation bar border? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to  set `View controller-based status bar appearance` in info.plist to `NO`.